# process name from ps command show ? instead of _ (question mark instead of underscore)

Tags: linux, process, locale

I have a specific linux CentOS 6 machine,
The processes I execute are:
test_statd, test_watch.

When i execute the follwing:

```
ps -eo comm | grep test_
```

I dont get response, so i execute this:

```
ps -eo comm | grep test
```

Now i get response, i see my proccesses, but they appear as:

test?statd
test?watch

instead of:
test_statd
test_watch

What is the reason _ was converted to ? as the process name.

This is the output of command ps -eo..

Thanks

Comment: Processes with underscores show up fine here; you tagged 'locale' -- does the behavior change with `LC_ALL=C ps ...` ?

Comment: From `man grep` on my CentOS 6.9 machine, the -w flag states it will only match if the match forms a whole word. A character is part of a word if it's a letter, digit, or underscore. From that, I would assume neither `test` nor `test_` should match `test_statd` if you pass the -w flag. Are you sure the output of your `ps` command really contains an underscore? The question mark reminds me of `ls`'s behavior when a filename contains an irregular character. If it's not an underscore, that would explain why `grep -w test` yields a match.

Comment: @KevinKruse removed -w. thats not the issue, sorry for that. thanks

Comment: @JeffSchaller i am not familiar with the locale in linux, all my labs are usually english, this is a situation happend on a customer machine, I am trying to reproduce, i changed the locale in my lab from en_US to fr_BE, LC_ALL= is empty on locale output.